# Integration testing

Tags: .net, nunit, integration-testing

I'm developing in .net and using NUnit.
I have tests for different classes and for each of the different modules.

What I need now is to test all the modules together!
the modules contact each other via DB and Tibco infrustructure.

How should I test all this symphony together ?

P.S. - if there's something more useful for this case than NUnit i'm open to suggestions.

Comment: That would be an integration test, not a unit test. It has a whole different set of problems and needs to be solved with different set of pattern. Nunit helps do unit tests, not necessarily integration tests. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If the classes called each other directly, it would be easy to write an integration test - simply call the top-level class without providing any mocks.  In your case, you might be able to:

1. Instantiate your first module
2. Make the appropriate method call, which should save to the database
3. Instantiate your second module
4. Make the appropriate call, which should retrieve the info saved in step 2
5. Etc.

I don't see a problem with using NUnit as the runner for this test. My suggestion would be to mark the test as Explicit so it does not run as part of a regular build or test run.

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion you should not integration test.

Unit test for basic correctness and acceptance test for the customer/product owner.

If however you can formulate an acceptance test in NUnit that is fine I think. I suggest you read [this](http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/post/1325858548/integrated-tests-are-a-scam). It is very opinoinated, but I agree.

For acceptance testing there are tools (for instance: [cucumber](http://cukes.info/) and [specflow](http://www.specflow.org/)), but they all depend on communication with the customer.

Comment: How can you possibly recommend not doing integration testing?

Comment: Because integration tests (or integrated testing) is really a bad idea [please see this video: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam ]. Definition: Integration test = testing an object with dependencies that you do not control. If you have critic of my answer please write why. Your comment does not help me to improve the answer.

Comment: Try telling that to the government rep when you're trying to win a contract with one of the branches of the military in your country. What he seems to be arguing in that video is that, since people aren't good at writing integration tests, you shouldn't even bother writing them. Can you not see the flawed logic there? Unit tests can cover discrete operations in objects, but integration tests can verify the correctness of the Unit tests and the design of the system. Running unit tests when checking in and integration tests for nightly builds is a perfectly valid way to do things.

Comment: You still do not help improving the answer, you simply just disagree with me. As J.B. Rainsberger mentions in the video Integration tests give a false sense of security. With integration tests you can only cover very few of possible paths through the code, which is what he argues is the main problem with integration tests. It really does not matter how good the integration test writer is. Integration tests can sometimes help when designing the system, but for testing basic correctness I do not think they are useful.

Comment: I apologize for the rude tone of my initial comment. I feel that you and J.B. Rainsberger are offering misleading advice. Of course integration testing, or any testing for that matter, cannot provide you with a guarantee of program correctness. However, the jump from units working according to a contract (unit testing) to units working in coordination to produce an efficient larger outcome (integration testing) is too large and important to be dismissed as "a scam." While I agree that it is not feasible or useful to provide 100% coverage with integration tests and it is definitely not feasible

Comment: to use any methodology to prove program correctness, we shouldn't dismiss integration tests as they are a very useful tool for checking a minimum level of functionality. My main experience comes from game development, where 100% integration test coverage is obviously impossible. Yet, if you look at this GameDev.SE thread (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/574/automated-testing-of-games) you'll see many people have had positive experiences with a certain amount of integration testing combined with manual testing.